# Are there any un-enchanted hoods that can be worn with other headgear?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

The Thieves Guild hood can be worn with additional headgear, and I've tested wearing it with the Archmage's Robes, Vokun/Morokei and an Ebony Helmet.

I couldn't understand why this only worked with the Thieves Guild Hood until I looked at my character: the Thieves Guild Hood resembles more a skullcap/coif and can be worn underneath any other headgear.

I'm looking for similar skullcap/coif headgear (un-enchanted) so I can place my own enchantments on it. Is there anything else like this in all of Skyrim?

My end-goal is to wear simultaneously two headgears with custom enchantments.

Comment: Wow, I didn't even realize that this was possible. Thanks!

Comment: Yeah, but it takes some experimentation as you have to equip them in the correct order. It also works for Archmage's Robes + Vokun + Thieves Guild Hood

Comment: This trick works with the Dark Brotherhood (Shrouded) headgear as well, but it comes with enchantments too.

Comment: Although as you pointed out graphically this looks OK, I still suspect it could be a bug. Can anyone weigh in on whether this (allowing certain headgear to be worn simultaneously with other headgear) is a bug or not?

Comment: For the record, I just found out this also works with the Thieves Guild Master's Hood as well.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can wear a falmer helmet and a circlet at the same time, with custom enchantments on both.

Comment: Indeed, and combining a Falmer Helmet with a Circlet enables one to further buff alchemy for silly-strong equipment in the alchemy+enchanting+smithing loop.

Comment: Is this the *only* piece?  Those Falmer helmets are *ugly*.

Comment: Only piece that I know of that's unenchanted.

Comment: The "Falmer Helmet of Peerless Repugnance". I'm not sure if the Thieves Guild and Dark Brotherhood headgear is a bug, but the Falmer Helmet trick most likely is.

Comment: just install the hide helmet mod and you'll be fine :P

Comment: Hmm, seems all possibilities have been explored, so marking this as answered.

Answer (score 0):

As you might know by now, there's an unenchanted version of the Dark Brotherhood's "shrouded cowl", which is just a tight, black hood.

You can get it by going through the Dark Brotherhood quest line and entering the Dawnstar Sanctuary. It's inside a hallway on a bookshelf, along with unenchanted versions of the other D.B. armor pieces. No unenchanted Dark Brotherhood robes though I'm afraid.